# jQuery Mobile reset dropdown form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to have a reset button on my form.

The code works, but it doesn't refresh the dropdown form. So it has value 0, but it doesn't show it's new value.

How can I solve this problem?

```
<script>
$('#btn-reset').live('click', function() {
$("select#Wiel").selectedIndex = 0;  //this works
    $("select#Wiel").selectmenu({'refresh': true});   /this doesn't work
});
</script>
```

Comment: On a side-note, do not use `live()`. `live()` has many issues, see documentation for the drawbacks and problems (http://api.jquery.com/live/). As of jQuery 1.7 `on()` is the preferred method to bind to dynamic/static elements. If you are using an older version use `delegate()` for dynamic bindings and `bind()` or `.click()` for static bindings.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select#Wiel").selectedIndex = 0;  // this works
```

No it doesn't work, because jQuery object has no `selectedIndex` property, you should convert the jQuery object to a DOM object first:

```
$("select#Wiel")[0].selectedIndex = 0;  // this does work
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('Wiel').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the jQuery object and showing the alternative to using just jQuery. Though I would recommend to OP to stick with jQuery if that is what is used as mixing it with plain JavaScript will probably just end up confusing.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks, you have always helpful and constructive comments, it's much appreciated.